# Once my action has been approved, and the app is still in sandbox mode, will my action be public to all users?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph, sandbox, public

My Open Graph action has now been approved. As the app isn't ready for launch, I was wondering whether actions published now using the app are now public to non-developers, testers and admins of the app? Or, because the app is in Sand Box mode, are these actions still hidden? I can't find an answer anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox mode makes your application not load for non-owner viewers. So everything it does will be invisible, including OG actions.

But as always, try it and let me know.

Comment: Thank's, all actions are still hidden.